# React Router Dom doesn't pass Function to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

making app connected to external API(Rails). The problem begins when I'm trying to sing in as a user on Login page. I fill my credentials set already in DB click Sign In and it will return JWT token and it suppose to pass function `propagateSignIn` that is defined in my `Route.js`.

**EDIT:** No prop is sent to `SignUp.js` page.. `console.log()` always returns empty `{}`

```
TypeError: _this3.props.propagateSignIn is not a function
```

**-- Router.js --**

its wrapped in `Router` and `Switch` component:

```
import SignUpPage from '../containers/SignUpPage/SignUpPage'

...

{
  !this.state.jwt &&
    <Route exact path="/sign_in" render={props => (
      <SignUpPage {...props} propagateSignIn={this.propagateSignIn} />
  )} />
}
```

The function is binded in construstor:

```
this.propagateSignIn = this.propagateSignIn.bind(this)

...

propagateSignIn(jwt, history = undefined) {
  const { cookies } = this.props
  cookies.set(this.state.cookieName, jwt, { path: '/' })
  this.getUser(history)
}
```

**-- SignUp.js --**

On that page i call method `handleSubmit` and calling API to authenticate user:
Api.authenticateUser(this.state.email.value, this.state.password.value).then(jwt => {

```
  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      formSubmitted: true,
      submit: {
        error: ''
      }
    })

    if (this.getFormErrors().length > 0) {
      return false
    }

    Api.authenticateUser(this.state.email.value, this.state.password.value).then(jwt => {
      if (jwt) {
        this.props.propagateSignIn(jwt, this.props.history)
      }
      else {
        this.setState({
          submit: {
            error: 'Sorry, we could not log you in with the credentials provided. Please try again.'
          }
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Thank for help.

**EDITED - console.log(this.propagateSignIn)**

```
ƒ propagateSignIn(jwt) {
      var history = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : undefined;
      var cookies = this.props.cookies;
      cookies.set(this.state.cookieNa…
```

Comment: Hi:
can we get a console.log() of `this.propogateSignIn` in the render method also do you definitely get !this.state.jwt?

Comment: I edited my question and added `console.log` to render method.. yes i do get it.. JWT token is generated right after click on `Sign In` button.. i have log for that

Comment: so there is a this.state.jwt? would that not make it `true`? it looks like only if you don't have a `this.state.jwt` will that Route exist?

Comment: The route renders fine, `!this.state.jwt` should be true at this moment..